# How to pass an actual object to method that takes an object reference

Tags: c++-cli

In a C++/CLI code block, I've got this sort of code:

```
{
    System::IO::StreamWriter sw("file");
    sw.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
}
```

The idea is that `sw.Dispose()` is automatically called at the end of the block, regardless of how it got there - either normally or by throwing an exception.

Now, I want to pass `sw` to a method defined in C# as `void foo(StreamWriter)`. This means that I can't simply call

```
foo(sw);
```

because `foo` expects a `StreamWriter^` and I'm passing it a `StreamWriter`. How do I pass a reference to `sw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the % operator! See [Tracking References in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a.aspx).

```
{
 System::IO::StreamWriter sw("file");
 sw.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
 foo(%sw); 
}
```